# Disabling HiDPI in a Mac OSX virtual machine

Tags: mac, vmware-fusion

I have installed Mac OS X in VMWare and I am running into an issue with my display. When I run the virtual machine full screen on my main monitor with a resolution of 1920 x 1080. Mac OS X insists that the screen resolution in 960 x 540, i.e. Mac OS X thinks the monitor is HiDPI. I have installed VMWARE Tools, vmware-resolutionSet to no avail. How do I disable HiDPI mode?

Answer (score 5):

With a little bit more digging I found this website https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/hidpi-mode-os-x/ which suggested running the following command in terminal window:

```
sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist DisplayResolutionEnabled
```

I then restart Mac OSX and hey presto the HiDPI was not present

Comment: Domain (/Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist) not found.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!